# Unity 3D Wheel Collider. How to detect if its touching anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know how to make it detect. I looked `public bool GetGroundHit(out WheelHit hit);` I cant put it anything it comes out as error. I want to make the level reset whenever the wheels of the car go off track on the tag "ground" but I have no idea how to do it and no yt videos to explain

Answer (score 0):

Add a collider to the wheel (can be mesh collider, sphere collider as long as it covers the wheel) add a collider to the ground (perhaps a box collider), make sure the wheel and ground are always touching when the wheel is on the road. In the road object make its name Road. Make sure trigger is deselected on both colliders, in the car script add,

```
OnCollisionExit(Collision other) {

    if (other.gameObject.name.Equals("Road")) {
    Debug.Log("Wheel has left the road");
    }

}
```

Comment: if i add any colliders to my wheel it breaks my car.

Comment: sounds like wheels have rigidbodies attached, workaround: create a separate object, make it a child of the car, it doesn't need to have a mesh it can be an empty object, add a collider, maybe a box collider, make sure its low enough to be always touching the ground and attach a script with the above code to it